# In terraform, what is the azurerm cosmosdb default_identity_type setting?

Tags: terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

What is the default identity type in CosmosDB in Azure?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account#default_identity_type

When I run my Terraform plan, the default_identity_type is getting updated, but I don't know what that is. Is there a place where I can see this value in the CLI, resource manager or the portal? What property in Azure does this setting correspond to?

Here is what the azurerm doc says:
default_identity_type - (Optional) The default identity for accessing Key Vault. Possible values are FirstPartyIdentity, SystemAssignedIdentity or start with UserAssignedIdentity. Defaults to FirstPartyIdentity.

There is an identity block, but that seems to be a different thing from default_identity_type.

The documentation says it is for using CosmosDB with key vault, but as far as I know, there are no special settings in the CosmosDB resource for using key vault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `identity` block defines the managed identity for ***cosmosdb account*** which currently can only be `System Assigned` and `default_identity_type` is for using one managed identity to access the key vault from the cosmosdb account for ***encyprtion purpose***.

The `default_identity_type` defaults to **FirstPartyIdentity** which means there is a default Identity with name `Azure Cosmos DB` which is used by all the cosmosdb resources in Azure and use it to access the keyvault like below ***example 1***. If you are using the `identity` block with **SystemAssigned** then you can mention **SystemAssignedIdentity** in the `default_identity_type` parameter as shown in the below ***example 2***.

**Example 1:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest-resources"
  location = "eastus"
}

## firstparty identity which is provided by Microsoft
data "azuread_service_principal" "cosmosdb" {
  display_name = "Azure Cosmos DB"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "ansumantestkv12"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "premium"

  purge_protection_enabled = true

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "list",
      "create",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "update",
    ]

  }
  # identity added in access policy
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azuread_service_principal.cosmosdb.id

    key_permissions = [
      "get",
      "unwrapKey",
      "wrapKey",
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "ansumantestkey1"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 3072

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "wrapKey",
    "unwrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
  name                = "ansumantest-cosmosdb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
  key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.versionless_id
  default_identity_type = "FirstPartyIdentity"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Strong"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

In this method the Identity that is used to access is the ***Default Azure Cosmos DB Service Principal***, so there won't be any details in the identity blade. Only in ***Data Encryption*** Blade you can see the key vault details.

**Example 2:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ansumantest-resources"
  location = "eastus"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "ansumantestkv12"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "premium"

  purge_protection_enabled = true

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "list",
      "create",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "update",
    ]

  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "ansumantestkey2"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 3072

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "wrapKey",
    "unwrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
  name                = "ansumantest-cosmosdb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "MongoDB"
  key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.versionless_id
  default_identity_type = "FirstPartyIdentity"
  #after deployment change to below
  #default_identity_type = "SystemAssignedIdentity"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Strong"
  }
  ##system managed identity for this cosmosdb resource
  identity {
      type="SystemAssigned"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

#providing access to the system managed identity of cosmosdb to keyvault 
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.identity.0.principal_id

key_permissions = [
      "get",
      "unwrapKey",
      "wrapKey",
    ]
}
```

In this example you cannot set `default_identity_type = SystemAssignedIdentity` while provisioning the cosmosdb account . Once the cosmos db is deployed with default identity type as firstPartyIdentity then you can modify it to SystemAssignedIdentity and then apply update on the cosmosdb block by using below command :

```
terraform apply -target="azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example" -auto-approve
```

**Outputs :**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the details. We don't have a System Assigned or a User Assigned identity on our CosmosDB account. Possibly for this reason, there is no Data Encryption blade even available in the UI. I think this setting isn't going to do us any harm. It just appeared when we upgraded our azurerm provider. Sounds like we can go back in and modify as needed, later.